# What are the operations which can cause KU$ objects to go invalid if NLS_CHARACTERSET and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET are different?

Tags: plsql, database-administration, oracle12.1

So, we are repeatedly getting the problem that the KU$_RADM_FPTM_VIEW gets into invalid state, along with 100s of packages and other objects. Unless you compile this view and it's associated type KU$_RADM_FPTM_T, none of the other objects get compiled and become valid. Oracle version is 12.1.

What I know so far--
--This issue belongs to NLS settings in the database, the national characterset and default characterset are different, due to which these objects get invalid as Oracle is unable to compile the type since it has nvarchar datatype.
--These objects are undocumented(as far as I know)
My question is, since these objects are not invalid all the time, what is the actual operation that puts these objects go into invalid state, so that practice can be avoided altogether instead of running manual script to compile these objects and then compile rest of the objects.

I wrote a script which basically gets the DDL of the invalid KU$ objects and then proceeds to compile invalids in the database. One option is to change the NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET, but that is a different analysis altogether.

Comment: You need to create an SR with Oracle Support to resolve this. You shouldn't be having to work directly with internal dictionary objects.